# The service on the integrator is not deployed

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

The message repository/message processor in Enterprise Integrator WSO2 is not deploying. Deployment fails with an error:

```
Couldn't find repository location './repository/deployment/client'
```

Versions:

- WSO2 enterprise integrator - 6.6.0
- Windows 10Pro - 20H2

Server :

- Linux -  CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
- CPE OS Name - cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
- Kernel - Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64
- Architecture - x86-64

Logs from `wso2carbon.log`:

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender} - Error initializing BlockingMessageSender org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Couldn't find repository location './repository/deployment/client'
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.<init>(FileSystemConfigur  ator.java:68)
  at org.apache.axis2.context.Configur tionContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.init(BlockingMsgSender.java:98)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor.initMessageSender(ScheduledMessageProcessor.java:489)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageProcessor.java:101)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.java:52)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.MessageProcessorDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(MessageProcessorDeployer.java:58)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:200)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1099)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:114)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
  at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
  at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

TID: [-1234] [] [2022-09-30 12:50:23,169] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.MessageProcessorDeployer} - Message Processor Deployment from the file : /opt/wso2ei-6.6.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1664531421939dwhErpTableCapp_1.0.0.car/dwhErpTableMP_1.0.0/dwhErpTableMP-1.0.0.xml : Failed. org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error initializing BlockingMessageSender
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.handleException(BlockingMsgSender.java:546)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.init(BlockingMsgSender.java:103)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor.initMessageSender(ScheduledMessageProcessor.java:489)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageProcessor.java:101)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.java:52)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.MessageProcessorDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(MessageProcessorDeployer.java:58)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:200)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1099)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:114)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
  at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
  at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Couldn't find repository location './repository/deployment/client'
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.<init>(FileSystemConfigurator.java:68)
  at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.init(BlockingMsgSender.java:98)
... 26 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2022-09-30 12:50:23,173] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} - Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /opt/wso2ei-6.6.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1664531421939dwhErpTableCapp_1.0.0.car/dwhErpTableMP_1.0.0/dwhErpTableMP-1.0.0.xml : Failed! org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Message Processor Deployment from the file : /opt/wso2ei-6.6.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1664531421939dwhErpTableCapp_1.0.0.car/dwhErpTableMP_1.0.0/dwhErpTableMP-1.0.0.xml : Failed.
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:483)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.MessageProcessorDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(MessageProcessorDeployer.java:77)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:200)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1099)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:114)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
  at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
  at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
  at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error initializing BlockingMessageSender
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.handleException(BlockingMsgSender.java:546)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.init(BlockingMsgSender.java:103)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor.initMessageSender(ScheduledMessageProcessor.java:489)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageProcessor.java:101)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.java:52)
  at org.apache.synapse.deployers.MessageProcessorDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(MessageProcessorDeployer.java:58)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Couldn't find repository location './repository/deployment/client'
  at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.<init>(FileSystemConfigurator.java:68)
  at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
  at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.init(BlockingMsgSender.java:98)
... 26 more
```

Directory in integrator :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rz5R.png)

Comment: Could you check whether the `[EI_HOME]/repository/deployment/client` folder exists in the file system?

Comment: This location should be available in the default pack. How did you start the WSO2 server? Did you start the server from a directory other than the `<EI_HOME>/bin` directory?

Comment: Also, although you say you are running on Windows I see Unix paths, `/opt/wso2ei-6.6.0/wso2`. Is there something we are missing here?

Comment: @sanoJ added image to main feild.

Comment: @ycr No, I did not do that. I don't know how the server was started.

Comment: @ycr I added changes in main field for more details.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW-- this does not look to be an ActiveMQ issue, but an Axis2 issue.

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Couldn't find repository location './repository/deployment/client'
```

Comment: I agree and I know that. Can you tell me how to fix this?